# How to handle functions that do not always return a promise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is the best way to handle situations when a function does not always return a promise? My actual code is too complicated to explain but the essence of the problem boils down to checking a condition and depending on it I either return a local variable or need to send an ajax request. 
Something like this:

```
function example(value){
   if(!value){
      return $http.get('www.example.com'); 
  }
   else {
      return "Your value is "+value; 
  }
}
```

Is there a way to check if the value returned by the function is a promise and needs to be resolved? Or maybe there is another approach to handle such situations? Thank you for your input!

Comment: Never write such functions in the first place! Just *always* return a promise.

Comment: Otherwise, `Promise.resolve(example(…)).then(…)` (or the angular equivalent) will do it

Comment: Better just always return promise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you can test to see if the return type is a `Promise`: `myValue instanceof Promise`, it is better to simply write functions that always return a `Promise`. That makes them consistent and much easier to deal with. In your example where you may need to return a `Promise` for an async function, or may need to return a value, just use `Promise.resolve()` with the value:

```
function example(value) {
  if(!value) {
    return $http.get('www.example.com');
  } else {
    return Promise.resolve('Your value is ' + value);
  }
}
```

That way, you don't have to worry about what it gives back and can always deal with it in a consistent way.

Answer (score 2):

You can return a promise always:

```
function example(value){
   if(!value){
      return $http.get('www.example.com'); 
   }
   else {   
      return $q.when("Your value is "+value); 
   }
}
```